# How to add copyright to Android-Studio?

Tags: android-studio, licensing

The title says everything. If I want to add copyright comment in code files in Android Studio?
I, of course, find the Copyright settings in Preference/Copyright, but I can't make it work... copyrights just don't appear when I create a new Java file.
Is it a bug of Android Studio or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

On the file you want to insert the copyright notice you have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for Windows and GNU/Linux or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for Mac and select the copyright to be inserted.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-and-updating-copyright-notice.html

Answer (score 37):

File > Settings > Editor > Copyright > Copyright Profiles > + add -> profile name

Sample Copyright Template Text

```
/**
 * Created by $username on $today
 * Copyright (c) $today.year . All rights reserved.
 * Last modified $file.lastModified
 */
```

If you need any extra variables, please visit source [Copyright Profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright-profiles.html)

Comment: Is there any command to get the file's actual created date instead of $today?

Comment: @krishnamurthy please follow this variables only available https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright-profiles.html

Comment: For new versions, Go to Android Studio> Preferences

Comment: marked the answer

Answer (score 27):

You need to first create a copyright profile (`Settings | Copyright | Copyright profiles`), then go to `Settings | Copyright` and change the default copyright.

Comment: Can I share my copyright between projects? Every time I create a new project, i have to add a new copyright profile to the new project which is annoying.

Answer (score 17):

Go to Settings> Copyright> Copyright Profiles. Create one copyright profile. Then go to Settings | Copyright and change the default copyright to the one which you created and Apply>Ok.

And from the top menu Click Code -> click Update copy right and select the files you want to apply.

Comment: Couldn't figure out why my changes weren't showing up. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thanks for explaining how to update default after adding the Copyright Profile.

Answer (score 10):

After you have configured the copyright settings and copyright profiles (`Settings > Editor > Copyright`) for your project, you can:

- (Windows) Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> in an opened file to present the option for adding/updating the copyright
- (Mac) Use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> in an opened file to present the option for adding/updating the copyright
- Right click a directory or file in Android Studio's project view, and select "*Update Copyright...*"

Answer (score 2):

You can find file header in Preference menu.

Android Studio - Preference - File and Code Templates

Select includes Tab. You can edit file header.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences | Search " Copyright " -> Add New Copyright Profile -> then select default copyright for project.

```
    Created by YourName on $today
    yourmail@gmail.com
    Last modified $file.lastModified
    Copyright (c) $today.year.  
    All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 2):

1 - To add or update copyright in android studio, go to Settings > Copyright > Copyright Profile (or Preferences > Editor > copyright in Mac).

2 - Create your copyright profile, add your message and apply the changes.

3 - Now again go to copyright, add the profile you created as the default copyright and apply the changes.

4 - Not go to Code option at the top menu and click on update copyright, select the scope(a file, or a module, or whole project as per requirement).

5 - In case you are updating the copyright again, it is possible that the update copyright option might now be activated, try restarting the studio or invalidating cache and restart. The option should be clickable.